# How to add a node to a System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode if it has no CreateElement() method defined?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have to add a new node to an XML document and Powershell doesn't let me to use the method CreateElement() where I would like my node to be placed.

I first get the content of the XML file like so:

`[XML]$val = Get-Content "path_to_XML_file"`

And use `$val.configuration.'system.webserver'` to naviguate to the node where I would need the new element to be placed.

`$val.configuration.'system.webserver'.GetType()` gives me `System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode`

When I do `$val.configuration.'system.webserver'|gm` it only gives me the following choices:

`ToString
AppendChild
Clone
CloneNode
CreateNavigator
Equals
GetAttribute
GetAttributeNode
GetElementsByTagName
GetEnumerator
GetHashCode
GetNamespaceOfPrefix
GetPrefixOfNamespace
GetType
HasAttribute
InsertAfter
InsertBefore
Normalize
PrependChild
RemoveAll
RemoveAllAttributes
RemoveAttribute
RemoveAttributeAt
RemoveAttributeNode
RemoveChild
ReplaceChild
SelectNodes
SelectSingleNode
SetAttribute
SetAttributeNode
Supports
WriteContentTo
WriteTo`

Since the node is a new one, trying to use AppendChild() has not been effective.

Is there another way to create the node?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the $val variable had the CreateElement() method. I just had to create the element from there and append it to the node I wanted the new item to be placed.

```
$DCBC = $Web.CreateElement('UrlCompression')
$DCBC.setAttribute('DynamicCompressionBeforeCache','false')
$Web.configuration.'system.webServer'.AppendChild($DCBC)
```